# How to create a certificate chain

Tags: go, ssl, http-proxy

I'm working on a proxy server for automating browser integration tests. I've gotten to a place where I can create a root CA cert and then my self signed cert.

However, where I'm failing is "joining" these together into a valid certificate chain that is then served. I feel like I'm missing something very trivial as the CA is created correctly and the self signed cert is being signed by the CA however the certificate chain never shows the CA when viewing the generated certificate within a browser.

I realize this is somewhat a cryptic question, but let me know how I can make this more clear.

Thanks everyone!

```
func Server(cn net.Conn, p ServerParam) *ServerConn {
    conf := new(tls.Config)
    if p.TLSConfig != nil {
        *conf = *p.TLSConfig
    }
    sc := new(ServerConn)
    // this is the CA certificate that is performing the signing and I had though would show as the "root" certificate in the chain
    conf.RootCAs = buildBoolFromCA(p.CA)
    conf.GetCertificate = func(hello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
        sc.ServerName = hello.ServerName
        // the self signed cert that is generated (the root CA however is not part of the chain
        return getCert(p.CA, hello.ServerName)
    }
    sc.Conn = tls.Server(cn, conf)
    return sc
}
```

To reduce the size of this post I created a small gist here to show where I'm generating the CA and the self signed certificate: https://gist.github.com/jredl-va/d5df26877fc85095115731d98ea5ff33

*Update 1*
Added get cert to gist

Comment: You omitted the most important bit: `getCert`. Aside: the RootCAs field is meaningless for servers.

Comment: Also note that the root certificate is not usually included in the chain. There's no point in doing so. Clients are expected to already have the root certificate in their pool of trusted CAs. Including them in the chain adds no useful information and just wastes bandwidth.

Comment: @Peter thanks peter, I'll update the post so that getCert is included within my gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go doesn't magically include the CA certificate in the TLS handshake. If you expected RootCAs to cause that, you are mistaken. It is irrelevant for servers:

> RootCAs defines the set of root certificate authorities that **clients** use when verifying server certificates.

You can either change GenerateCert to return the whole chain:

```
--- cert.go.orig        2019-09-18 17:35:29.408807334 +0200
+++ cert.go     2019-09-18 17:35:45.028779955 +0200
@@ -46,11 +46,11 @@
        x, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, template, ca.Leaf, key.Public(), ca.PrivateKey)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        cert := new(tls.Certificate)
-       cert.Certificate = append(cert.Certificate, x)
+       cert.Certificate = append(cert.Certificate, x, ca.Leaf.Raw)
        cert.PrivateKey = key
        cert.Leaf, _ = x509.ParseCertificate(x)
        return cert, nil
 }
```

... or make getCert append the CA cert in a similar fashion:

```
--- cert.go.orig        2019-09-18 18:07:45.924405370 +0200
+++ cert.go     2019-09-18 18:08:11.998359456 +0200
@@ -61,7 +61,8 @@
 func getCert(ca *tls.Certificate, host string) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
        cert, err := GenerateCert(ca, host)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
+       cert.Certificate = append(cert.Certificate, ca.Leaf.Raw)
        return cert, nil
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! That was my missing piece. And yes your assumption was correct.